# discrete math identity set question

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Let $S=\{a,b\}$ be a two-element set. How many functions $f:S\rightarrow S$ have  the property $f \circ f$ is the identity function?

one or two or three?

This is my university discrete math question, however, i am really out of thought for this one.
I understand the identity function is that we give $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x$, but for $f \circ f$, the only thing i can thought is $f(x) \times f(x)$, am i right?

thanks for Tim's correction, the $f \circ f$ stands for $f(f(x))$ not $f(x) \times f(x)$

Comment: Wait now I misread

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: OP, explain your thoughts...or you shall not receive an answer.

Comment: You have only two choices for $f(a)$ and for each one there are only two choices for $f(b)$, so start trying them. Maybe you will see a pattern that will let you not try them all, but it isn't many

Comment: @DonLarynx I'm sure OP is quivering at that threat.  The ellipsis made it especially dramatic.

Comment: @Tim, funny. In all seriousness, it is straight to the point. I am sure he prefers one sentence over a long arduous "welcome" paragraph.

Comment: @OP: $(f\circ f)(x)=f(f(x))$.  Functions that satisfy $f(f(x))=x$ are called _involutions_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I saw a correct solution that was posted earlier but the solver deleted it. So to satisfy the OP's request, I rewrite that answer here: 
There are only 2 functions to meet the requirement. One is f = Id, and the other is f with $f(a) = b$ and $f(b) = a$. Check : $f(f(a)) = f(b) = a$, and $f(f(b)) = f(a) = b$. So $f*f = Id$.

Answer (score 3):

To have a hope that $f\circ f(x)=x$, $f$ has to be surjectivity-why? How many of those are there? Do they all work?

Comment: Did you really mean to write "$f(x)\circ f(x)$" there?

Comment: @ Henning Makholm: Thanks